# Twilio handle message emoji reactions

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

Asking for a help on how can I handle message emoji reactions with Twilio API. I have looked at its documentations and read countless threads but can't seem to find a resolution. Is there a workaround on how to implement an emoji reaction to a message with Twilio? Thanks!

Comment: handle message emoji reactions like where a user texts an emoji to a Twilio number? Can you share some code?

Comment: Not exactly. What I want to do is like on Facebook messenger's emoji reaction to a message but on SMS. I just like to check if anyone has made some workaround to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio does not currently support emoji reactions to messages, which I clarified via a support request, and coming across this [Twilio Help Center post](https://help.twilio.com/articles/19191283763355).

You will instead receive a message with a 'null' body and no other information on it.

Perhaps it was supported at a stage, but not currently.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I presume you mean that the Twilio phone number is the sender here.

You can see if someone reacts to a message from a Twilio phone number in your Messaging Logs in the console! Below is a screenshot reflecting when I loved a message sent to me from a Twilio #.

[image: screenshot of twilio messaging logs showing someone loved a message]
You could then write some code (ie. with a few conditionals?) to handle different reactions (such as a love (the heart), like (the thumbs-up), dislike (the thumbs-down), laughed at (the haha), emphasized (exclamation marks), questioned (question mark)). The status of the message with reaction received is always "Received." [More on that in the Message Status docs here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/message-resource#message-status-values).

There are some quickstarts to track delivery statuses of messages ([node.js](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-confirm-delivery-node-js#receive-status-events-in-your-web-application), [python](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-confirm-delivery-python), [etc](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-confirm-delivery))

Comment: I am not seeing any message body in the log when I react with emojii in Whatsapp to a message sent by a sender using webhooks. I see the message in the logs and receive it on my server but the body is blank. None of the data in the log or server request identifies the message being responded to or the emoji reaction. Is it possible to handle these reactions?

Comment: @lizziepika As Ollie Glass mentioned, there's no body included in response messages, or any field populated on a Message resource response to indicate what the reaction is - I suspect there may have been an update to remove this from the Twilio Messaging API since your last response

Answer (score 0):

You have to write code to ignore or handle these messages specifically
This is my code so I don't send a message back to these incoming messages.

```
      if ((sms.Body.StartsWith("Like “")
      || sms.Body.StartsWith("Liked “")
      || sms.Body.StartsWith("Loved “")
      || sms.Body.StartsWith("Disliked “")
      || smsBody.StartsWith("Removed a heart from “")
      || smsBody.StartsWith("Removed a like from “")
      || smsBody.StartsWith("Removed a dislike from “")) && sms.Body.EndsWith("”"))
  {
      skipResponse = true;
  }
```

Comment: This is very iOS specific. Android will not response like this.